# Remove elements from ArrayList while retaining the duplicates if any present

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to remove some elements from an ArrayList.
I used `removeAll(List)` method.
But the problem with this is it removes the duplicates as well.
How do I retain the duplicates?

Consider below example -

I have a `List a1 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3}`

Now I have another

```
List a2 = {2, 3}
```

When I use `a1.removeAll(a2)` I get `a1 = {4, 5}`
This removes all the instances of 2 and 3.

What I need is `a1 = {4, 5, 2, 2, 3}`
Just the number of instances present in a2 should be removed from a1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You have 2 items in `a2`, do you want to remove only if they are in same sequence in `a1` as that of `a2`. What happens if `a1` is `{3,4,5,2,2,3}` and `a2 = {2,3}`? Will the end result be `{4,5,2,3}`? Unless you do not clarify on these points, no one can write code which suits your requirement.

Comment: Can a2 contain duplicates?

Comment: So, show us the code you've written and explain what isn't working for you.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate the second list and for each member call remove() on the first list. You can't do this with a single call.

And be sure to invoke remove(Object) - instead of remive(int)! In other words: makes sure that you pass an Integer object. Otherwise you will be invoking the wrong method that removes a certain index!

Comment: Nice. Answering a codeless "show me how to do this" question with an algorithm instead of code.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using map as this avoids n*m time complexity. Keep count of all elements in a1 & a2 . Then decrement the a1 count & add it to new Arraylist based on the a1 count map.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> a2= Arrays.asList(2,3);

        Map<Integer,Integer> a1Count = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,Integer> a2Count = new HashMap<>();

        a1.forEach(a -> {
            int count = a1Count.get(a)==null ? 0: a1Count.get(a);
            a1Count.put(a, count+1);
        });

        a2.forEach(a -> {
            int count = a2Count.get(a)==null ? 0: a2Count.get(a);
            a2Count.put(a, count+1);
        });

        a1Count.forEach((key,value) -> {
            if(a2Count.containsKey(key)) {
                a1Count.put(key, value-a2Count.get(key));
            }
        });

        List<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<>();

        a1Count.forEach((key,value) -> {
            if(value>0) {
                for(int i= 0; i<value;i++) {
                    removed.add(key);
                }
            }
        });




        System.out.print(removed);
    }
```